# Проверка пересекаются ли прямоугольник и круг, вписан ли круг в прямоугольник или нет

Tags: c#, геометрия, прямоугольники

Мой код:

```
using System;

public struct Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"(X:{X},Y:{Y})");
    }
}

namespace Lab1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Point P1 = new Point();
            Point P2 = new Point();
            Point P3 = new Point();

            Console.Write("P1\nX: ");
            P1.X = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Y: ");
            P1.Y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("P2\nX: ");
            P2.X = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Y: ");
            P2.Y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("P3\nX: ");
            P3.X = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Y: ");
            P3.Y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("r: ");
            double r = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Точка P1"); P1.Print();
            Console.Write("Точка P2"); P2.Print();
            Console.Write("Точка P3"); P3.Print();

            double heightRectangle = Math.Abs(P2.Y - P1.Y);
            double widthRectangle = Math.Abs(P2.X - P1.X);

            Point centerRectangle = new Point();
            center.X = (P1.X + P2.X) / 2;
            center.Y = (P1.Y + P2.Y) / 2;


        }
    }
}
```

Как я могу проверить круг вписан в прямоугольник или описан или круг пересекается с прямоугольником либо пересечений нет?

Comment: У Вас стороны прямоугольника параллельны осям координат?

Answer (score 1):

Я увидел координаты трех вершин треугольников, увидел координаты центра прямоугольника - центр отрезка P1P2 стороны треугольника. Размер вашего прямоугольника также известен, выходит, что отрезок Р1Р2 это есть диагональ прямоугольника. Но я не нашёл что у вас за круг и его координаты. И ещё вопрос:

1. Круг может быть вписан лишь в особый случай прямоугольника - в квадрат.
2. Круг описан вокруг прямоугольника - значит его центр совпадает с точкой пересечения диагоналей прямоугольника.
3. Как проверить пересечение прямоугольника и круга, это просто:
   Взять уравнение круга и взять уравнение отрезков сторон прямоугольника, если у них есть общие точки, значит есть пересечение.

Comment: Извиняюсь, центр круга - точка P3, радиус переменная r

Comment: 'if (r <= Math.Min(heightRectangle, widthRectangle) / 2 && Math.Abs(center.X - P3.X) <= r && Math.Abs(center.Y - P3.Y) <= r)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Круг вписано в прямоугольник");
            }
            else if ((P3.X == center.X && P3.Y == center.Y) && r >= diagonalLength / 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Круг описано");
            }
            
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Круг и прямоугольник не пересекаются. ");
            }'

Answer (score 0):

```
var rect = new Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
bool yes = rect.Contains(new Rectangle(0,0,50,50));
```

Определяет, находится ли указанная точка в пределах прямоугольной области, определенной данным прямоугольником Rectangle.

---

```
var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
var newRect = Rectangle.Intersect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50), new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30));
```

Возвращает третью структуру Rectangle, представляющую собой пересечение двух других структур Rectangle. Если пересечение отсутствует, возвращается пустая структура Rectangle.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersect?view=net-7.0